# What is this choko-like vine, and how can I get rid of it and ensure it doesn't return?

Tags: identification, weed-control, weeds

What is this choko-like vine, growing near Toowoomba, Australia? What is the best method to permanently get rid of the plant?

The first picture shows the 'fruit' hanging on the vine, which is growing amongs some camellias. Te second photo shows the leaf shape (sorry it's blury). The vine does sometimes have white flowers.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Araujia sericifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araujia_sericifera). Its common names include Moth Plant, White Bladderflower, Common Moth Vine, Cruel Vine and False Choko.

Here is some basic information about eradication of it: [Weedbusters.org](http://www.weedbusters.org.nz/weed-information/araujia-hortorum/59/)

And even more comprehensive are: [landcareresearch.co.nz](https://www.landcareresearch.co.nz/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/77911/Ecology_pest_status_moth_plant_Araujia_hortorum.pdf) and [aphis.usda.gov](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/plant_health/plant_pest_info/weeds/downloads/wra/Araujia%20sericifera%20WRA.pdf).

[image]